# limit string to 10 chars jquery on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a jquery function

```
$('.class').reducetext(10);
```

function is

```
$.fn.reducetext=function(length){
    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,length))
}
```

i will put this in document.ready
$('.class').reducetext(10);

so it will reduce string of .class elements

what i want is

these '.class' elements will load dynamically using ajax

so every time when ajax is calling 
i can call $('.class').reducetext(10);

but i don't want to call this on every ajax call

within one call i want to do this

if it is a click or any similar events  i can use "on"
But for this what code i should write?

Comment: I am not so sure if it would work but give a try to `$('.class').on('change',function() { $('.class').reducetext(10); });`

Comment: `i don't want to call this on every ajax call` Why??

Comment: Your only option is to add that method to the returned content inside the success handler of the specific ajax calls you want to change

Comment: @RahulDesai ajax call is in different plugin so i have to edit in many places which will take toomuch of time

Comment: Jeezes, just add this in the [**AjaxSuccess**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) handler, and it runs on every ajax call. What does it matter if it's called on every ajax request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't neet to re-use the `$('.class').reducetext(10);` because you're not handling any event with `.class` element. Event delegation is done for dynamically created elements but no need to use for simple use case like you're having...

Such thing like `$(elem).text('...')` would be applied even for dynamically created elements.

But wait! You're using ajax call to insert the element then you have another option so that you can register the methods like `$('.class').reducetext(10);` just once. To this, you need to use:

```
$(document).on('DOMSubTreeModified propertychange',function(){
   $('.class').reducetext(10);
});
```

For IE, you use propertychange method.

Comment: So you're saying that all the elements loaded later with ajax will automatically get the text sliced when inserted as long as that plugin is ran at pageload ?

Answer (score 1):

For best performance, add `$('.class').reducetext(10);` in the success handler of the AJAX call.

It will be an overhead setting up another function and running it just for that.

---

*In response to your comment:*

AJAX is not a seperate plugin. It is built-in in Javascript and jQuery.

Readup:

- [`jQuery.ajax()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [Javascript AJAX | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: ajax call is in different plugin so i have to edit in many places which will take too much of time my problem is i should not touch other plugins. so that i have to add a common function in a common js file

Comment: @user3797053 Sorry, I think you are under a wrong impression about using plugin for AJAX. Please refer the links in my answer above. You DO NOT need a 3rd party plugin to do AJAX.

Comment: i am using many plugins like datatables, jquery.form,jput,jformslider, etc etc all these plugins has ajax functions with success. but my project has gone so far so editing all these plugins success function is very difficult for me, thats why in one common js file i want to have a common function to reduce text.Bhojendra Sah answer was correct in my case. thanks for your support